# meteor i18n for web and mobile: getting user locale right

Tags: meteor

I plan to deploy my app made in Meteor in three different countries, and I am not sure what's the best way to achieve i18n. I am using [tap-i18n](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n) package, which works well for translating strings. But I am not sure how I should decide the current user's locale. I thought of deciding based on the user's location (using an api that translates loc/lng to country code) but that seemed too heavy. After a second thought, this is my plan.

1. Have three different root-level endpoints `/english`, `/chinese`, `/japanese`.
2. For web users, decide locale based on their brower's setting (perferred-langauge meta tag) and redirect them appropriately.
3. For mobile users, hardcode app's url to the app store's appropriate language (ex. set it to /english if I am publishing it to U.S. App store)

I don't know if this is the best approach. Could anyone advise?